# Append a changing variable to a list and then compare them

Tags: python-3.x, list, function, append

I have a Python 3 code that scrapes data from a website which results a single variable called “total”. The variable “total” is a dollar amount. I have code that runs the script every 15 minutes so I can see if the variable “test” has changed. This code works perfectly. I now want to insert code that runs a function if “total” has gone up in dollar value since the last time the script has run. I believe it should look something like:

If total > total_last_time then run def()
Else run the code again in 15 minutes

The problem is that I am a newbie (but learning quickly) and I don’t know how to save the variable “total” and then compare it to the next time the code runs and returns the new “total” variable. My guess is that I need to create a list and append each new “total” variable result to the list and compare the last 2 entries against each other. Is this correct and how do I accomplish this?

Comment: `totals = []` at the beginning. And then each time a total is retrieved,  `totals.append(total)`. The comparison (after the append) is then : `if totals[-2] < totals[-1]:`.  Python takes negative indexes to index starting from the end. Thus,  `totals[-1]` is the last value, the one you just appended.

Comment: This didn't append to the list. It just gave [[...]] as the list over and over. The "209.90" is the `print(total.text)` line output from my code and the `[[...]]` is the output from your suggestion of `total.append(total)`. Here is the output from letting it run 3 times using "while". ```$209.90
[[...]]
$209.90
[[...]]
$209.90
[[...]]```

Comment: Correction @AuleMahal, I did not use "while" to loop. I used something else I found on YouTube using def(main) at the beginning. Is there a way I can copy/past my whole code (26 lines) without going over the character limit?

Comment: You could try to remove parts of your code that aren't vital for this question or use a service like pastebin.com .

Comment: Here is my code: ```import time
from selenium import webdriver

def main():

    pricelist = []
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    browser.get('XXXXX.com')
    time.sleep(3)
    price = browser.find_element_by_id('priceblock_ourprice')
    price = price.text
    pricelist.append(price)
    print(pricelist)

    browser.close()

    restart = "yes"
    if restart == "yes":
        main()

main()```

Comment: Could have used pastebin, as I suggested, this is hard to read. Also, I suggest you read more about python in general and try tutorials as you can easily find on the internet. Here what happens is that `price_list` only exists in the function, since you declared it in the function. Thus, when the function is exited, it is forgotten, appending is useless.

Comment: OK...thanks for your help. I had a suspicion the function was causing the append to not work as I wanted it too.